# Oracle - subprogram or cursor c_tab is out of scope

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure CV8_POCET_RADKU(p_schema VARCHAR2, p_razeni IN varchar2 default 'asc') as
i_dotaz varchar2(200) := 'select count(*) from ';
i_pocet number;  
cursor c_tab is 
  select object_name
  from dba_objects where object_type = 'TABLE' 
  and owner = upper(p_schema) 
  order by object_name asc;

  i_tab c_tab%rowtype;
begin 
dbms_output.put_line('Tabulky ze schematu: ' ||p_schema);
open c_tab;
loop
  fetch c_tab into i_tab;
  exit when c_tab%notfound;
  execute immediate i_dotaz || p_schema||'.'||i_tab.object_name into i_pocet;
  dbms_output.put_line(c_tab.object_name || ' - '|| i_pocet || 'radku');
end loop;
close c_tab;
end;
```

Oracle give me a error subprogram or cursor c_tab is out of scope. I think i have the cursor right.

Comment: It is always helpful to include the full error stack which would include the line number of the error.  That would make it much easier to identify the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in the line which reads:

```
dbms_output.put_line(c_tab.object_name || ' - '|| i_pocet || 'radku');
```

You can't refer to `c_tab` like this - instead, refer to the row variable you read the data into:

```
dbms_output.put_line(i_tab.object_name || ' - '|| i_pocet || 'radku');
```

Best of luck.